# Laravel login form MAMP fail - mac

Tags: laravel-4

I developed laravel 4 app on win7.
Now I try deploy it on Mac with MAMP.

everything seems to work except for a strange login issue:
when I click on my sign in form, the auth::attempt passes, and then the code redirect to 'profile' page.

but on MAMP I get the following message instead:

```
array(3) { ["_token"]=> string(40) "E2qYigaryiBNvzV2I7HUFdmp6gdtWaqFKXrVWwWO" ["email"]=> string(14) "elia@gmail.com" ["password"]=> string(4) "elia" } Redirecting to http://localhost:8888/wm/public/profile.
```

it seems like the login process went find but than instead of doing the actual redirect it send a string/serialised version of the redirect object...

any idea how to solve this?

Here is my code (the actual login code is from a tutorial):

```
public function login()
{
    $input = Input::all();

    $rules  = array('email' => 'required|email' );
    $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if ($validation->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors(array('message' => 'Login field is required.'));
    }
    if ($validation->passes())
    {
        $credential = array('email' => $input['email'] , 'password' => $input['password']);
        if (Auth::attempt( $credential)) {
            Auth::user()->history()->create(array('event' => 'logged in'));
            return Redirect::to('profile');
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors(array('loginError' => 'Wrong email or password.'));
        }
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors($validation->getMessages());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A small fix: instead of

```
return Redirect::to('profile');
```

do:

```
return Redirect::intended('profile');
```